# R: kmeans on matrix (100x21)

Tags: r, matrix, k-means

I have a question about Kmeans in R. I have a dataframe like variable data_file. My question is, how can I perform kmeans on my data? If anyone has any suggestion, you are more than welcome. Thank you!

```
> data_file

                    WT_Sham WT_Sham.1 WT_Sham.2 WT_Sham.3 WT_Sham.4 WT_Sham.5 WT_CSD WT_CSD.1 WT_CSD.2 WT_CSD.3 RQ_Sham RQ_Sham.1 RQ_Sham.2 RQ_Sham.3 RQ_Sham.4 RQ_Sham.5 RQ_CSD RQ_CSD.1 RQ_CSD.2 RQ_CSD.3
ENSMUSG00000002012     581      1221       681      1789       376       787   1009      480      992     1004     582       896      1319      1200       663      1089   1003      821      807      696
ENSMUSG00000028182       2        11         3         8         2         8      1        3       12        3       1         5        35        13         0         1      8       13        5        1
ENSMUSG00000002017     382       698       555      1290       892       999    546      245      689      539     367       548       927       905       853       623    823      722      494      505
ENSMUSG00000028184     381       666       443       763       491       655    621      376      379      353     382       306       878       690      1787       257    776      636      240      564
ENSMUSG00000002015     402       956       533      1728      1224      1129    668      383      930      355     481       704      1611      1458         0       345   1199     1017      653      917
ENSMUSG00000028180     778      2158      1506      3606      2489      3128   1573     1030     1962      956    1093      1410      3702      3122         1      1433   2535     2125     1242     1825
```

Comment: http://www.mattpeeples.net/kmeans.html ??

Comment: Did you try the built-in function `kmeans`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the built in function `kmeans`?

```
kmeans(USArrests, centers=3)
```

`USArrests` is just a data set that comes with R.

---

If you google `R kmeans` you will get more information.